# Recovering corrupted OneDrive files

Tags: onedrive, reparse-points

I wanted to backup my OneDrive for Business folder to an external HD (I use Veeam) and that has not been possible for a while, since some update by Microsoft.

This morning I did some research and I stumbled upon this:

https://forum.acronis.com/comment/451003#comment-451003

I blindly followed the advice and typed

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
fsutil reparsepoint delete $file.FullName
}
```

into PowerShell, from the OneDrive folder.

After execution, I tried to backup *some* files and it worked. (Note that due to this, I have today's backup for just some of the files.) Yay, I thought.

However, after a few hours, my changes had propagated and my coworkers were unable to open DOCX and XLSX files. Any of them - `Cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid`.

`Open and Repair` from inside Office is not working.
Restoring yesterday's OneDrive is not working (the files have been overwritten with new ones of the same name).
Microsoft's help desk will contact us back!

Help! We have an old backup but we cannot afford to lose 2 weeks work! Is there any way to undo the reparsepoint thing, or to recover the corrupted Office files?